# Php - how to run python

Tags: php, python, shell

I'm getting this error:

```
    ************************ EXCEPTION: N5boost11filesystem316filesystem_errorE 
boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/.dogecoin" dogecoin in AppInit() 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error' what(): 

boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/.dogecoin" Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my index.php:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>';

$output = array();

echo shell_exec("python genNewAdd.py 2>&1");


echo phpinfo();

 ?>


</body></html>
```

And heres genNewAdd.py:

```
def genNewAdd():
        c = csv.writer(open("/home/dogecoin/bin/addresses.csv", "a"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        os.system("/home/dogecoin/bin/dogecoind getnewaddress > /home/dogecoin/bin/temp_address.txt")

        temp = open("/home/dogecoin/bin/temp_address.txt")

        my_add = 'DRAnDvLedqHjC84DrcZfLC2dNBREDnTUj4'
        adr = temp.read().strip();
        c.writerow( [adr, my_add])
        temp.close()
    print adr;
        return adr;
genNewAdd()
```

I'm trying to run "genNewAdd.py" from my php file and get the string it returns in the terminal.

Comment: This is a server permissions problem.  Also, like, a bad idea™.

Comment: I've tried fixing it by giving user "www-data" read/write permissions to the directory. Didn't work though.

Comment: I don't know that this would fix your problem, but why not rewrite that Python code in PHP and cut out one possible failure point?

Comment: I still need to execute the command at /home/dogecoin/bin/ so I don't think that would fix it.

Comment: I looked briefly at the Dogecoin code and it looks to have some sort of RPC mechanism. Perhaps you could take a look at that for a more solid way to do it.